# Error al instalar apk con Android Studio : DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android

he creado una app de un feed de un blog y hasta ahí no me da ningún error.
A la hora de probarlo compila bien, pero al instalarlo me aparece esta ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aun teniendo la app desinstalada, le de a ok o cancel, abajo a la izquierda sale un cartel que dice:
Session 'app': Error Installing APK.
La palabra app es un vinculo que te lleva a la ventana de Run app, en la que aparece lo siguiente:

> 09/19 13:46:09: Launching app $ adb push
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\FeedCharcuteriaJJEE\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/feedcharcuteriajamoneseutiquio $ adb shell pm install
>   -r "/data/local/tmp/feedcharcuteriajamoneseutiquio" pkg: /data/local/tmp/feedcharcuteriajamoneseutiquio Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
>
> $ adb shell pm uninstall feedcharcuteriajamoneseutiquio
>   DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APK

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR  se debe a multiples causas, Comentas que no se tenia instalada, podrías agregar cual es el paquete definido en tu build.gradle o manifest.xml ?

Comment: Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida al sitio!, es importante realices el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te 
da información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida 
en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si alguien sigue teniendo este problema, les digo la solución que se me ocurrió (luego de horas de búsqueda sin éxito). Como Android Studio intenta instalar un APK para correr el emulador, se me ocurrió eliminar el APK existente del proyecto.

Fui a la carpeta del proyecto, donde está localizado el archivo "app-debug.apk"; (en mi caso "\NOMBRE_DEL_PROYECTO\app\build\outputs\apk\debug"), y para no perder ningún dato (ya que soy nueva en esto), modifiqué el archivo "app-debug.apk" por "app-debug.apk.txt" (de forma que Android Studio no lo reconozca e intente instalar nuevamente el APK). Luego cerré el emulador, y le di "Run" de nuevo. A la primera no me funcionó del todo bien, ya que estaba instalando el APK mientras corría el emulador, por lo cual tuve que cerrar el emulador de nuevo, y correrlo otra vez. Ahora está funcionando sin problemas!

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente configuración:
Mi AVD es un Nexus 4 corriendo Android Oreo (API 27), cuya configuración gráfica es "Software - GLES 2.0" (por defecto, al instalar AS viene como "Automática", y eso genera otros problemas al correr la app).
Además estoy en un Windows 10, utilizando Android Studio 3.1.4.

Espero a alguien le sea de ayuda!

PD: Este es mi primer post :)

Comment: Yo tenía el mismo problema pero incluía mi dispositivo. usé clean proyect, para asegurar.

Answer (score 1):

El error que describes:

> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APK

puede tener múltiples causas, me parece que la más común es el uso de **"Instant Run", deshabilitalo** y vuelve a subir tu .apk al dispositivo o emulador:

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el nombre del paquete es: feedcharcuteriajamoneseutiquio.Mañana intentaré la solución del instant run.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla Ok es correcto, deshabilita "instant Run" y  trata nuevamente.

Comment: La respuesta de Jorgesys me ha funcionado. Adjunto pantalla en versión 3.4.2.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4usX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4usX.png)